# disable click of main slideshow (div?) on front page in koken (repertoire theme)

Tags: html, css, click, koken

I don't know CSS or html very well, only a little. All I want is for the slideshow on the front page of my website to not be click-able. I want it to be there to view but I don't want people to be able to click it (which leads to it's album view.) In the back page of koken, there is a Custom CSS area to add extra code to change the theme. 
Is there something I can put there to stop the main slideshow from being click-able? I need to know specifically what to put.

I think the div is either `"home-slideshow"` or `div.pulse-main-container`.

I tried

```
div.pulse-main-container.click(function () { 
  return false; 
});
```

but I don't think that's how you even write it out. I don't know what to put, that's why I need someone to spell it out for me.

I use "inspect element" with my browser to look at the code, but it's all gobble-de-gook to me. This doesn't seem like a hard thing to fix but for the life of me I can't figure it out!

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: idk what my cms is. but .home-slideshow{pointer-events: none;} was the answer for me. Thanks to the two fellows at the bottom for helping! :)

Comment: not sure who gets the answer, because they both helped me!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.home-slideshow').css({
     'pointer-events':'none'
});
```

Comment: Don't you think this would work better as a css rule? .home-slideshow{pointer-events: none;} . I don't see the need for jQuery since this is a css3 rule.

Comment: @Pavan Try explaining your answer.

Comment: @MohammedAlsaedi Yes it works with css actually. Since the approach made by her was through click events handling my thoughts were gone through that way lead me to this answer.

Comment: I tried using both in the custom css section and also before the end body tag and neither of them worked. However, when I used the .home-slideshow{pointer-events: none;} in the custom css it worked!

Comment: Thank you both! @MohammedAlsaedi The CSS Rule version of the "pointer-events" thing saved the day! :)

Answer (score 0):

put this somewhere in your html. (maybe right before the end of your body tag).

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
   $('.pulse-main-container').click(function(){
      return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: this didn't work for me but the suggestion you said in the other guys answer did! Thank you!